# Convertir número entero a tiempo en PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo un número en una base de datos que se muestra de la siguiente manera: **330**. Debe mostrarse en minutos como: **5:30**.

Si el número **330** es dividido entre 60 segundos el resultado es **5.5** que equivale a cinco minutos y medio: **5:30**.

Esta es la variable:

```
$videoDuration = get_field('video_duration');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claro puedes aplicar la función `date()` para eso, así:

```
date("i:s", $videoDuration)
```

Quedaría así:

```
<?php

  $videoDuration = get_field('video_duration');
  $tiempo = date("i:s", $videoDuration);

?>
```

Puedes verlo funcionar [aquí](http:////phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%5Cn$videoDuration%20=%20330;%5Cnecho%20date(%22i:s%22,%20$videoDuration);%5Cn%5Cn?%3E%5Cn).

Comment: Ese código sólo funcionará mientras el valor sea inferior a `3599`. Si la duración llega a una hora o más arrojará resultados erróneos. No sé cuál sea el alcance de los requerimientos (sobre todo en cuanto a formato de presentación), pero creo que convendría algo más robusto como crear un verdadero objeto `DateTime` o usar la función `gmdate`.

Comment: Gracias por la acotación @A.Cedano